# Agent dose not move with internal brain when build for ml-agent

Tags: unity-game-engine, machine-learning, ml-agent

The problem I have is that when I build my game with the brain set to "Internal" type and the graph model set, agent dose not move. But when I press the ▶️ button in Unity, agent moves.

I understand training method and I have graph model.

I want to move agent with .exe(build) file.

Development environment
・Windows 10
・ml-agents v0.5.0
・Unity 2018.2.18f1 Personal

Answer (score 0):

You are not very clear in what you have done or what your question is, but for using the internal brain, make sure you put your `runid.bytes` file inside the brain. Which is obtained after the training process has reached `max_steps`.

To train your agent with an executable file:

1. Build your project
2. Go to command line and go to the `ml-agents` folder on your computer. (Mine is located under `C:/Users/alexl/ml-agents`)
3. Run `mlagents-learn config/trainer_config.yaml --env="PATH/TO/EXE/EXE" --run-id=RUNID --train`

**Make sure to not include the file extension in path. For example C:/unityproject/project instead of C:/unityproject/project.exe**

Now after the training process has finished, go to `/ml-agents/models` and here you will find a `RUNID.bytes` file. Put this into the internal brain and now press start in the Unity editor.

Comment: Finally what I want to do is not inference with pressing start in the Unity editor and inputting command but inference with double-clicking .exe(build) file 
like an ordinary game.

Comment: It's not exactly done by manually opening the .exe file, but the command in step 3 of my answer will run the .exe file and once you hit play it will behave the same way as it would in Unity.

Comment: Exactly. But I want to use ML-Agents(internal brain) for my Indie game, so I need to make  .exe(build) file and run ML-Agents(internal brain)  in only .exe(build) file.